# Startbootstrap clean blog template flaw

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem with the clean blog template from start bootstap.
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to the nav-bar but the menu items do not show when the nav bar is at the top of the page. Once you scroll down a little though, the menu items will appear. 
[image]

[image]

I know this has to do with the transition from the clear navbar design to the white background navbar design. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Code:

```html
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UBC Guidebook</a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li>
                          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Learn <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li>
                                  <a href="pages/academics.html">Academics</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <a href="pages/culture.html">Campus Culture</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <a href="pages/involved.html">Getting Involved</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <a href="pages/adventure.html">Adventure</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <a href="pages/food.html">Places to Eat</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="about.html">About</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
      </nav>
```

```css
/*!
 * Clean Blog v1.0.0 (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2014 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under Apache 2.0 (https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

body {
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #404040;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
a {
  color: #404040;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #0085a1;
}
a img:hover,
a img:focus {
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
blockquote {
  color: #808080;
  font-style: italic;
}
hr.small {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: white;
}
.navbar-custom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
  .navbar-custom .nav li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .nav li a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed {
    /* when the user scrolls down, we hide the header right above the viewport */
    position: fixed;
    top: -61px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .navbar-brand {
    color: #404040;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #0085a1;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .nav li a {
    color: #404040;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .nav li a:hover,
  .navbar-custom.is-fixed .nav li a:focus {
    color: #0085a1;
  }
  .navbar-custom.is-visible {
    /* if the user changes the scrolling direction, we show the header */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}
.intro-header {
  background-color: #808080;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.intro-header .site-heading,
.intro-header .post-heading,
.intro-header .page-heading {
  padding: 100px 0 50px;
  color: white;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro-header .site-heading,
  .intro-header .post-heading,
  .intro-header .page-heading {
    padding: 150px 0;
  }
}
.intro-header .site-heading,
.intro-header .page-heading {
  text-align: center;
}
.intro-header .site-heading h1,
.intro-header .page-heading h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.intro-header .site-heading .subheading,
.intro-header .page-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro-header .site-heading h1,
  .intro-header .page-heading h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
.intro-header .post-heading h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
}
.intro-header .post-heading .subheading,
.intro-header .post-heading .meta {
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block;
}
.intro-header .post-heading .subheading {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.intro-header .post-heading .meta {
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.intro-header .post-heading .meta a {
  color: white;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro-header .post-heading h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
  }
  .intro-header .post-heading .subheading {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
.post-preview > a {
  color: #404040;
}
.post-preview > a:hover,
.post-preview > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0085a1;
}
.post-preview > a > .post-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.post-preview > a > .post-subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.post-preview > .post-meta {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.post-preview > .post-meta > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404040;
}
.post-preview > .post-meta > a:hover,
.post-preview > .post-meta > a:focus {
  color: #0085a1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .post-preview > a > .post-title {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
.section-heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
footer {
  padding: 50px 0 65px;
}
footer .list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer .copyright {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.floating-label-form-group {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.floating-label-form-group input,
.floating-label-form-group textarea {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  resize: none;
}
.floating-label-form-group label {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  line-height: 1.764705882em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.floating-label-form-group::not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
  color: #0085a1;
}
form .row:first-child .floating-label-form-group {
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}
.btn-lg {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px 35px;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  background-color: #0085a1;
  border: 1px solid #0085a1;
  color: white;
}
.pager {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.pager li > a,
.pager li > span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.pager li > a:hover,
.pager li > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0085a1;
  border: 1px solid #0085a1;
}
.pager .disabled > a,
.pager .disabled > a:hover,
.pager .disabled > a:focus,
.pager .disabled > span {
  color: #808080;
  background-color: #404040;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #0085a1;
}
::selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #0085a1;
}
img::selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
img::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: #0085a1;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: or at the very least, the css. It is a css question after all.

Comment: My fault, I've added the code I used for the nav bar. The styling and javascript are just the files downloaded from startbootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Give your navbar a class like

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default some-class-name navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">`

Then use that to target the links in the dropdowns which are currently white, and make them a diffrent color with css like:

```
.some-class-name.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu  li a{
  color:#888686;
}
```

You'll also want to cover the "in use" type states with something like:

```
.some-class-name.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu  li a:hover,
.some-class-name.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu  li a:focus,
.some-class-name.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu  li a:active,
.some-class-name.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu  li a.active{
  color:#fff;
}
```

#### [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/ycz3dm6k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this would be the CSS rule that is causing it, you shoukld change that to a different color and then you wont have to add a sepearte style rule for the li a's. And you will need to alter the next rule as well for the hover and focus colors.

```
  .navbar-custom .nav li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```